# Playing short selfmade sound with immediate start in iOS

Tags: ios, audio, avaudioplayer, core-audio, playback

I have a self-generated DTMF sound (with a wav header) generated by program that I want to be able to play quickly, in fact as soon as the user touches a button. This DTMF sound must play/loop infinitely, until I stop it. Some other sounds must be able to be played at the same time.

I'm very new to Audio programming, and I tested many ways of doing that and I'm lost now.

How can I achieve that ?

Needs :

- very quick playback start (including the first time)
- many sounds at the same time (short sounds +- 2-6 seconds)
- infinite DTMF sound without gaps
- having control over the different sounds that are playing /  being able to stop just one played sound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`AVAudioPlayer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) if you can live with some latency, OpenAL (for example [Finch](https://github.com/zoul/Finch)) if you really need to have the latency as low as possible.

Comment: Actually you can get rid of this latency by queueing the track in advance. that way when you play it you get a hot start.

Comment: How hot? Last time I measured it was always at least 20 ms or so, which is too slow for many purposes. But it’s long time since I tried, so maybe the situation got better.

Comment: Exactly. OpenAL performs better. It’s easy to spot the difference when the sounds are bound to some time-sensitive input like tapping.

Answer (score -1):

I use already exist .wav file. and I can easily play it.

For run following code. include AudioToolbox framework.

write into .h  file `#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>`
Write into .m file

```
-(IBAction)startSound{

    //Get the filename of the sound file:
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], @"/sound1.wav"];

        //declare a system sound
        SystemSoundID soundID;

    //Get a URL for the sound file
    NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO];

    //Use audio sevices to create the sound
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)filePath, &soundID);
    //Use audio services to play the sound
    [self sound];
    timer =[ [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.1 target:self selector:@selector(sound) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]retain];

}
```

Comment: I don’t think system sound services are a good fit for this. How is the latency? Can you loop the sounds without skipping? Can you stop individual sounds?